# Match angular {{name}} with name in json array and get the corresponding data of that name from Json array

Tags: javascript, html, angular

so i am working with angular and i have a alert box with a text field that takes the input ({{name}}) and gives something like Welcome {{name}}. I want to match this {{name}} with my json array data which has name and a specific id.

What i want is the to match the {{name}} with json array name and get the corresponding id of that name. And also get only the last 4 digits of that id.

JSON data:

```
var json=[{
name="bob",
id="FYW1985274"
},{
name="tom",
id="FYW1687647"
}]
```

JS

```
function xyz{
 var loginName = document.getElementById("login").value

  var search = json.map(d => d.name)

if(search.includes(loginName)){
  json[i].id // i should be index of matching name // I do not know how to get corresponding id with last 4 digits for that name.
}
```

```
HTML
<welcome id="login" name="{{name}}"></welcome>
```

When i am trying to get name with id="login" it's giving me entire "Welcome name" but i want only name.

So the expected output should be something like

```
i/p: name="tom"
o/p: 7647
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly find the id by iterating over the array and searching for the name.
The find method on arrays will be useful here

```
function xyz{
 var loginName = document.getElementById("login").value

  var id= json.find(user => user.name === loginName);

// id now contains the id of the user whose name is entered in the input field
 console.log(id);
}
```